# Invalid Argument error in IE7 - jQuery tabs and Google Map

Tags: jquery

I have tried to rectify this 'Invalid Argument' error in IE7 so many times, but still it pops up...
it seems I am not getting to the actual reason of this error. Though it runs fine in Firefox.

Here is my code which I have moved to a html file for testing purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>jQuery Tabs and Google Map</title>   
    <style>
        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs li.active a {
            color:#fff
        }
        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs li a:hover 
        {
            color:#fff
        }     
        a, a:link, a:visited
        {
            color:#ff3333
        }
        ul.tabs li a:hover { 
            background:#ff3333;
            color:#fff
            }   
        ul.tabs li.active a
        {
            background:#ff3333;
        }  
        #pp_wrapper .tab_container {
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left; 
            width: 580px;
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs {
            height: 44px; 
            width: 940px;
            border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
            border-style: solid;
            float: left;
        }
        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs li {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 2px;
            padding: 0;
            height:auto;
            line-height:1.2;
            width:94px;
            height:50px;
            position:relative;
        }
        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            width:94px;
            padding: 6px 2px;
            height:auto;
            position:absolute;
            text-align:center;

            bottom:10px;
        }

        #pp_wrapper ul.tabs li a span 
        {
            font-size:1.1em;
        } 
    </style>       

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pp_wrapper">
        <div id="content">

            <div id="tabs">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tabs-22581"><span>Description</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-22582"><span>Map</span></a></li>
                 </ul>

                <div class="tab_container">

                    <div class="tab_content" id="tabs-22581">
                        <p>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Golf has been played on the Links at St Andrews since around 1400 AD and the Old
                            Course is renowned throughout the world as the Home of Golf.<br />
                            <br />
                            The game grew in popularity and by the 19th century it was part of the way of life
                            for many local people, whether as players, caddies, ball makers or club makers.
                            Golf still plays a major part in the culture and economy of St Andrews today. As
                            the 600 year history of the Links has unfolded, one simple track hacked through
                            the bushes and heather has developed into six public golf courses, attracting hundreds
                            of thousands of golfing pilgrims from around the globe.<br />
                            <br />
                            St Andrews Links is the largest golfing complex in Europe and all 18 hole courses
                            can be booked in advance. The Castle Course, the seventh co</p>
                       <p>
                            Price: £15,050,000.00</p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab_content" id="tabs-22582">
                        <p>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div id="GoogleMap_Canvas" style="width: 410px; height: 450px;">
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

                var mapLat = '51.509663';
                var mapLong = '-0.599329';
                var mapContainer = 'GoogleMap_Canvas';
                var mapTitle = 'Map Tester';

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    //When page loads...
                    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
                    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
                    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

                    //If first tab is having GoogleMap_Canvas, InitialiseGoogleMap()
                    if ($(".tab_content:eq(0)").has('#' + mapContainer).length > 0) {
                        InitialiseGoogleMap();
                    }

                    //On tab Click Event
                    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
                        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
                        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
                        $(".tab_content").removeClass("activeContent");

                        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active div(tab_content) 'id' 
                        $(activeTab).addClass("activeContent");
                        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
                        //This is needed for showing google maps inside the tabs instead of the window load event. Will avoid the issues with tabs and googlemaps.
                        if ($(activeTab).find('#' + mapContainer).length > 0) {
                            InitialiseGoogleMap();
                        }

                        return false;
                    });

                });

                function InitialiseGoogleMap() {

                    var googleCanvas = document.getElementById(mapContainer);
                    if (googleCanvas != null) {
                        var point = new window.google.maps.LatLng(mapLat, mapLong);
                        var myOptions =
                    {
                        zoom: 16,
                        center: point,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: window.google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        scaleControl: true,
                        mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                        map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapContainer), myOptions);
                        var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: point,
                map: map,
                title: mapTitle
            });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                    }
                };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Please run above file in IE7 (with javascript debugging enabled).
When I switch between tabs back and forth, I get javascript 'Invalid argument' error.

Can anyone please guide me the possible reason and fix of this error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that IEs<9 are running into trouble when map rendering is issued while previous map didn't finished it's work yet.

That said, you'll probably need a way to *know* when current map has finished it's rendering, some callback or something.

As described in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461246/google-maps-api-v3-is-there-a-callback-or-event-listener-for-a-setmap-event), so just under your marker.setMap(map); you can set up a callback like:

```
 marker.setMap(map);
 mapIdle = false;
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
      mapIdle = true;
 });
```

, of course you'll have to have var mapIdle defined globally, e.g. just under the mapTitle definition:

```
 var mapTitle = 'Map Tester';
 var mapIdle = true;
```

, and finally you should prevent (or at least to postpone it if there is a need to redraw the map) InitialiseGoogleMap(); when switching tabs if previous map job hasn't finished yet (if mapIdle still equals to false):

```
 if ($(activeTab).find('#' + mapContainer).length > 0 && mapIdle) {
```

instead of just

```
 if ($(activeTab).find('#' + mapContainer).length > 0) {
```